# path combined with filter - with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I am querying data from an API which has nested object properties that I need to access.

```
const players = teamsData && teamsData.team && teamsData.team.players;
```

I am using `path` to get this data.

```
const players = path(['team', 'players'], teamsData);
```

This works but when I combine with filter I get an error.

Ideally I want to use `pipe` and combine this with Ramda's `filter` method.

My code looks like this:

```
const injuredPlayers = pipe(
   path(['team', 'players'], teamsData),
   filter(player => player.isInjured)
);
```

Comment: What is `teamsData`?

Comment: The native array filter doesn’t check for undefined. Try using the ramda filter?

Comment: @evolutionxbox updated the question.

Comment: Try using path without providing `teamsData`, and pass it into `injuredPlayers`.

Comment: If you just want the list of injured players, you can write `const injuredPlayers = filter (player => player.isInjured) (path (['team', 'players'], teamsData)`.  If you want a *function* that will retrieve that information from `teamsData`, then you can write `const getInjuredPlayers = pipe(path('[team', 'players']), filter (prop ('isInjured')))` and call it with `const injuredPlayers = getInjuredPlayers (teamData)`.  Your code is combining these two distinct styles.

Comment: thanks @ScottSauyet. Would you mind adding that as an answer, feel other people would find that information valuable

Comment: @peterflanagan: added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does look like the players variable equals

```js
const players = path(['team', 'players'], teamsData);
```

at least from the code you wrote

will continue here if it's not a problem

at first I would prefer to use pathOr instead is going to look like this

```js
const pathTeamPlayers = R.pathOr([], ['team', 'players']);
const isInjured = player => player.injured
const filterInjured = R.filter(isInjured)

const teamDataToInjuredPlayers = R.pipe(
  pathTeamPlayers,
  filterInjured,
);

/* result */


teamDataToInjuredPlayers(teamData)
```

Comment: Thanks! why would you use `pathOr` as a matter of interest

Comment: @peterflanagan in case there is no such path or its undefined
your code will always run without errors

Comment: this leads to the following error: `First argument to _arity must be a non-negative integer no greater than ten`

Comment: @peterflanagan need more context 
I would ask you to take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wgkga6
works fine there

Comment: @peterflanagan got it now
pretty sure that the reason is that pipe expects you to pass functions but you pass the result instead
pipe(path(['team', 'players'], teamsData) ....
path(['team', 'players'], teamsData) - is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216436/discussion-between-peter-flanagan-and-shandor-kostur).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the list of injured players, you can write

```js
const injuredPlayers = 
  filter (player => player.isInjured) (path (['team', 'players'], teamsData)
```

If you want a *function* that will retrieve that information from `teamsData`, then you can write

```js
const getInjuredPlayers = pipe (
  path('[team', 'players']), 
  filter (prop ('isInjured'))
)
```

(or use `pathOr` with `[]` to increase reliability) and call it with

```js
const injuredPlayers = getInjuredPlayers (teamData)
```

Your code is combining these two distinct styles.